# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error on Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, signals, sigabrt

I searched this problem on site but I could not solve problem. So I want to ask that how I can solve this?

I have a navigation controller and a view controller. I add some elements on navigation controller, it's working but when I add a `ViewController` and I connect it with navigation controller, I see a problem. I connected them with segue and I want to pass to view controller from navigation controller's elements. Build failed and I take this error code;

```
2016-07-11 14:35:38.243 seg[4175:594378] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'


*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd73d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c7e7deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010d8f7ca9 __copy_helper_block_ + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010d871630 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 460
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010d871433 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010d8716f7 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d271156 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1775
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d27141b -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 388
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d135f62 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d149e4c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d156147 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc98c37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc98ba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc8e7fb __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc8e0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001105f3ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d129f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    17  seg                                 0x000000010c2e445f main + 111
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f54d92d start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

[my viewControllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faBGy.png)

Comment: problem in segue identifier

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: are you using [self performsegue identifier] in your code

Comment: you have to embed the controller in navigation controller from which you are performing segue

Comment: I did it on storyboard, I didnt use performsegue method, I choose navigationcontroller, and I just connected them with KNTRL then I chose push on selection segue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**embed Navigation Controller to your source view controller**

1. Select the source view controller
2. Go To **Editor**--> **Embed In** --> **Navigation Controller.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I did it but problem still continues

Comment: are you targetting intial view right? can you show your screen. at the same time can you try to remove the navigation controller and add again in the Intial ViewController

Comment: can you capture your storyboard screen using ( cmnt + shift+4) and updated in the question

Comment: I added it under my question

Comment: remove your tableviewcontroller

Comment: Why must I remove it?

Comment: just backup your code and do the step to rectify your error

Comment: but I want to reach view controller from cell's elements, if I remove tableViewController, how can I do that?

Comment: check my last image. you can change storyboard like this

Comment: Thank you I can pass to the view controller, I see back button but after 2 minutes, it will break down and I take this errors.

2016-07-11 15:52:23.084 seg[4826:622776] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<myTableViewController: 0x7fa44a46a800>) has no segue with identifier 'ShowMainMenu''
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a3dd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001064b1deb objc_exception_throw + 48

Comment: 2   UIKit                               0x0000000106f916aa -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
 3   seg                                 0x0000000105fae62c -[myTableViewController showMainMenu] + 60
 4   Foundation                          0x00000001060982c9 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 402
 5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106997074 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
 6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106996c21 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1089

Comment: 7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106958b11 __CFRunLoopRun + 1937
 8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001069580f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
 9   GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a2bdad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
 10  UIKit                               0x0000000106df3f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
 11  seg                                 0x0000000105fae37f main + 111
 12  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010921792d start + 1
 13  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: this is next problem. tableviewcontroller ----> viewcontroller ---> drag to poin the push--> after add the segue identifer name

Comment: what have you wrote code in the back button function

Comment: this error occur for missing or wrongly enter the segue identifier "Receiver (<myTableViewController: 0x7fa44a46a800>) has no segue with identifier 'ShowMainMenu'' " Check your segue identifier name

Comment: I didn't define any segue, I pass to viewcontroller from tableviewcontroller with KNTRL + drag.

Comment: check the last image like this you will add the segue identifier and [self performSegueidentifie:@"passIdentifiername"]

Comment: Thanks for everything! I really wasn't doing that for 2 weeks.

Comment: @HüseyinBakan accept my answer. its motivating me to help other. if any help mail me phrkrish@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I'd say the problem is that your segue's source controller is not contained in a NavigationController. To fix this, select the respective controller in InterfaceBuilder, open the `Editor` menu and select `Embed in`, then `Navigation Controller`. This will create a new NavigationController hosting your ViewController, and should also autoamtically update and fix the segue.

Comment: I did it but I saw same problem